# What is the sample space of a spinner in this scenario?

Tags: probability, definition

Say a spinner has 8 equally divided wedges, 1 yellow, 2 pink, 2 blue and 3 green.

Which of the following would be the sample space?

- {yellow, pink, blue, green}
- {yellow, pink, pink, blue, blue, green, green, green}

I am thinking of when I was taught years ago and now I'm not so sure. Using the first set, the formula for simple probability wouldn't hold:

$$P(event)=\frac{n(favorable\ outcomes\ of\ event)}{n(outcomes\ in\ sample\ space)}$$

in which case the probability of landing on any color would be 1/4.

I know this is quite pedantic but I would love an answer!

Comment: I'm pretty sure {yellow, pink, blue, green} is your sample space. It also depends on what you're doing... Are you spinning the spinner $1$ time or $3$?

Comment: You could take {yellow, pink, blue, green} as the sample space, but then that formula won't apply (because the outcomes are not equally likely).  To use the formula, you can take the sample space to be the set {yellow, pink_1, pink_2, blue_1, blue_2, green_1, green_2, green_3}. (Note: To be a set, all the elements must be distinct; so we can just distinguish them in some convenient way, e.g. subscripts.)

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to take for the sample space the set of wedges: $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and define the random variable $X(\omega) = \text{color of } \omega$.